# ag-grid get current page number

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

anyone know how to get the current "pageNumber" from ag-grid ?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use agGrid api by using

> gridOptions.api.paginationGetCurrentPage();

Reference URL: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-pagination/

Answer (score -5):

console.log(pages[0].pagenumber);

```js
console.log(pages[0].pagenumber);
```

Comment: you will get error with this command: Uncaught ReferenceError: pages is not defined